# I am trying to order the results of a mySQL query with 2 rules however I can't get the correct output

Tags: mysql

I am trying to order the results of a MySQL query by order of 'Amount (descending)' and then UserName (ascending)' however I'm not getting the results I'm looking for.

```
SELECT UserName
     , Sum(Amount)
  FROM UserPowerUps
 GROUP 
    BY UserName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UserName) = 1
 ORDER 
    BY Amount DESC
     , UserName ASC;
```

---

Above is the MySQL code and below is the query output.

---

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HrwL.png)

Comment: May be you want order by Sum(Amount) column, not amount. Give it an alias and try again

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the sum to an alias should do the trick

```
SELECT UserName, Sum(Amount) as sumAmount
  FROM UserPowerUps
  GROUP BY UserName 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UserName) = 1
  ORDER BY sumAmount DESC, UserName ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the instruction **sum** in the **order by** clause:

```
SELECT UserName, Sum(Amount)
FROM UserPowerUps
GROUP BY UserName 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UserName) = 1
ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC, UserName ASC;
```